# Category pages disabled javascript functions

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

When I go to a category page on my Magento installation since a couple of weeks I do not have a working search/mobile menu/language switcher:

https://www.thefixedgearshop.com/beat-the-heat-sale

When trying to switch the language in a category it adds a # and doesn't open the JavaScript that is needed. When on Homepage/CMS page/Product page everything works great.

I cannot figure out where the bug is taking place. The Console doesn't tell me enough.

Answer (score 0):

In your category page, I get this error in the console `TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function common.js (line 42, col 2)`.
I think this error occurs before the bootstrap js can do its magic so the whole js execution stops.
Try to remove the occurrences of `owlCarousel` from `common.js` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, that worked I think. The problem is procuded in the compression of the JS files.